# All Windows appear minimized and un-maximizeable

Tags: window-manager, ubuntu-mate

Sometimes (under Ubuntu MATE 16.04) I apparently press some evil shortcut, and all windows get minimized to the sidebar (Panel).

Strangely, I can not un-minimize (restore, maximize) them. Also opening a new Terminal (<kbd>ctrl–T</kbd>), that Terminal starts minimized. So cannot even restart the windows manager…

Clicking on them in the sidebar or plank, briefly shows the animation lines of opening/closing, perhaps showing the window for a millisecond, but that's about it…

[image]

All I can do in such situation is to reboot…

**Any advice, what's wrong?**

Switching to console and back (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6/F7</kbd>) does not help.

I am not talking "Hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop" from the keyboard shortcuts. I have a shortcut for that, I am aware of it, and minimizing as well restoring with that does work. Must be something different…

Comment: Does clicking twice on *"Click here to hide all windows and show the desktop"* (the *Show Desktop Button* on `mate-panel`) help? Is it possible that these windows were moved to the other/second screen?

Comment: I removed that from Panel. (But sounds identical to above „Hide all normal...“-Shortcut).